# Why is getchar() function in C an Integer?

Tags: c, getchar

Up to now, i have found out that, we use getchar() as int because at EOF this function returns -1. I was wondering can't **char** hold -1 ? i think it can,because it can also range from -128 to 127.

I searched through the top list of google, but the answer i got didn't satisfy me.

Comment: So what happens when someone actually types the character whose code is `-1`

Comment: just prints -1, i tried that too.. I think when getChar() returns -1, it's different then just typing -1 through the keyboard! @M.M

Comment: I said the character whose code is `-1`, not the characters `-` and `1`

Comment: Oh! my bad.. I can't find a character that represents -1! So is that what you are trying to convey? that there is no representation of -1 when we use char as type? @M.M

Comment: There might be one, and if there is, then you can't tell whether they typed that one, or EOF happened. Some systems give `ÿ` the code `-1`

Comment: Ok, i'm getting something now, Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, just to clear something up, `EOF` is not required to be specifically -1. The ISO C standard requires it to have a negative value.

Also note that the type `char` can be signed or unsigned; that is implementation-defined.

The function `fgetc`, `getc` and `getchar` can be used to process binary streams, not only text streams. Bytes have values from 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`. The natural type for this range is `unsigned char`.  The return value of `getc` couldn't be `unsigned char`, because `EOF` wouldn't be representable. It couldn't be `signed char` either, because `signed char` cannot hold the values from 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`. So, a wider type is chosen: the type `int`. On mainstream platforms, `int` is wider than `char`: it has a size of at least 2. And so it it is capable of representing some negative value that can be used for `EOF`, and all the byte values in the range 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`.

In some C implementations (for systems such as some DSP chips) this is not true: `int` is one byte wide. That represents challenges. On such a C implementation, a range of valid byte values returned by `getc` just has to be negative, and one of those values clashes with `EOF`. Carefully written code can tell that this is the case: a value equal to `EOF` was returned, yet the `feof` and `ferror` functions report false: the stream is not in error, and end-of-file has not occurred. Thus, the value which looks like `EOF` is actually a valid byte.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on EOF < 0, not necessarily EOF = -1.

Answer (score 4):

`getchar()` and family return an integer so that the EOF `-1` is distinguishable from `(char)-1` or `(unsigned char)255`.

Comment: i'm a bit confused right now, i tried to search for (char) of -1 but i can't find it? i just see positive numbers on the table! @ J Earls

Comment: If by "table" you mean the US ASCII chart or something, yes, those will all be positive numbers.  However, the C `char` type is an 8-bit **signed** integer type.  It represents numbers from 0 to 127 and from -128 to -1 rather than from 0 to 127 and 128 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

Chars, using Ascii encoding, is stored using a byte, which is unsigned 8-bit integer. Thus chars can take the numeric value 0-255.

getchar returns a signed int to allow for -1, which is the magic number for end-of-file (EOF)